What is the difference between once and cut in prolog?
once/1 can be defined as
once(Goal) :- Goal, !.

I am trying to understand the difference between those two examples that appeared in the discussion in SWI Prolog's docs:

Note that this is absolutely not the same as using "cut": [...]
Once-ify the first clause:
foo(A,B) :- once(member(A-B,[a-1,b-2,c-3,a-4])).
foo(A,B) :- member(A-B,[d-5,e-6,a-7,f-8]).

Then:
?- foo(a,B).
B = 1 ;
B = 7 ;
false.

But if you cut at the end of the first clause:
foo(A,B) :- member(A-B,[a-1,b-2,c-3,a-4]),!.
foo(A,B) :- member(A-B,[d-5,e-6,a-7,f-8]).

You get:
?- foo(a,B).
B = 1.


I'm not following what's the scope of !. I would assume that those two are the same, i.e. the cut propagates out of once, but this does not seem to be the case. Could someone explain how cut works in the once example?

See https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/programming-cooperation/5623/20?u=brebs

@brebs it doesn't seem to answer it

Yes, "logical captain" has been sailing the high seas. A lot of their comments on the SWI-Prolog documentation website are very confusing. Disregard everything you see in the comments to the docs if logical captain has written them. I don't want to discuss the examples you have copied from there because it is difficult to get something useful out of it.

look at it like this: cut belongs to the predicate it appears in. even if defined by two clauses, foo predicate is one predicate. cut appearing in one of its clauses, means it belongs to the foo predicate. when it appears in a predicate like once called by foo, it belongs to that predicate, not to foo.

Cut does not propagate out of the once/1. In fact, the once/1 definition:
once(Goal) :-
    call(Goal), !.

is exactly like that so that the !/0 doesn't get out.
The cut in this once/1 definition works like this: whenever the call(Goal) succeeds for the first time (it might have failed 0, 1, or more times before that!), then the cut is reached, all pending choice points created by you Goal are discarded, and you succeed "once" and for all.
